# How to show folders from google drive with drive apis in javascript

Tags: jquery, google-drive-api, drive

I know how to show all files which is in google drive but how to show folders also from google drive with drive apis in javascript

```
 function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              /*appendPre("<a href='"+file.id+"'>"+file.name + '</a> (' + file.id + ')');*/
              document.write("<a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id="+file.id+"'>"+file.name + '</a> <br>');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }
```

this function shows all files which is in drive already and it also work fine but please let me know about folders also?

check my whole code also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drive API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Drive API Quickstart</p>
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive"></iframe>
    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '*********';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listFiles();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              /*appendPre("<a href='"+file.id+"'>"+file.name + '</a> (' + file.id + ')');*/
              document.write("<a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id="+file.id+"'>"+file.name + '</a> <br>');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }

addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true));
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To list just folders, you can use the `q` (query) parameter and the `mimeType` for folders `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` . Here's an example based on your own `listFiles()` function that lists folders that have not been deleted:

```
function listFolders() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 1000,
          'q': "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Folders:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              document.write("<a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id="+file.id+"'>"+file.name + '</a> <br>');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No folders found.');
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thanx fo this but when  also put this code they cant show files on it only showing its folders

Comment: Great, this save my day, but i have another query that what if i dont want root folders , instead i want to list all the sub folders whos id is 'blaahblaah'?

Answer (score 0):

In GDrive, folders **are** files so your code will list all files regardless of whether they are images, spreadsheets, presentations or even folders.

Looking at your code, you have `pagesize=10` so your code will only display the first 10 files. To get "all file" you need to iterate on `!!nextPageToken`.

Comment: ohk thanx for help but after this they also shows folders? as same as like files?

Comment: yep. files and folders look almost identical. The only way to tell which is which is by looking at the mimeType. Folders have a mimeType of "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

Comment: thanx for respond but please can uh put code here so i easily understand that?